# JSX is not returning from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Here value prop  is ["hello world"]

it's a simple array of one value string and the given function below is not returning JSX.

```
const list = ({value}) => {
    return (
        <div>
        {
            value.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
                console.log(item, index)
                return <div>{item}</div>
            })
        }
        </div>
    );
}

export default list;
```

Comment: `forEach()` returns `undefined` use `map()` instead

Comment: The code will return a jsx element as long as the file it is exported from is .jsx / .tsx and not .js / .ts

A few notes to your code:
- The array `value` should be called `values` since it is an array and holds multiple values.
- Use `.map` instead of `forEach`
- Use proper indentation to avoid confusion.
- Don't know why you would put a console.log in the returning jsx. If you want to check the values, then console.log before returning or use the debugger to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is doesn't return anything. you should use `Array.map` instead!

```
const list = ({ value = [] // Default value }) => {
    return (
        <div>
        {
            value.map((item, index) => {
                console.log(item, index)
                return <div>{item}</div>
            })
        }
        </div>
    );
}

export default list;
```

Comment: if map is used then it says "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead "

Comment: What does `value` contains?

Comment: you'll get that error if you render directly Object `{}` instead of values, If you can show the placeholder data, we can see!!